# outlook Template insert Variable Data

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, email-templates

I need to send an e-mail out every day and the format is same, only things that changes is some Ticket numbers.

So to automate this, I am creating a outlook add-in and I retrieve the dynamic data throw API calls, Now I need to put that data in desire format.

Is there a way to use outlook template and just insert Dynamic data via C# code from add-in.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a custom .oft template? What item properties do you want to populate?

Comment: yes .oft template, 
I want to dynamically add some rows to a table.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Application.CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865637.aspx) method with the path to the .oft file as a parameter.  Then you can cast the returned object from the method to a MailItem variable and populate the .Body or .HTMLBody property with your dynamic message content.